# (Mercurial/tortoisehg) Lost commits - how to troubleshoot

Tags: version-control, mercurial, dvcs, tortoisehg

A colleague of mine was working on a VS project this morning, which he claims was in a folder clone of our central repository. He built a release version of the application which is still there with the correct date/time stamp on it.

He then said he committed several times during this time, but at some point, he tried pulling down changes from the central repository and merge them in with his changes. He can't really remember what steps he took, but the end result is that all the changes he did to the source were lost. now, i'm trying to help him to see if we can recover any of those changes.

He told me after he committed his changes (several commits), He went into the tortoisehg workbench, pulled, and saw that there were many changes in the central repository. He decided to either "Merge with local" or "Update" to the tip pulled down - he can't remember which. I showed him the two dialogs, and asked him if he discarded changes, shelved or anything else. He couldn't remember, really, but he did remember he had to back out because tortoisehg didn't like what he was doing. Eventually, he did seem to be able to update to the repository tip.

I'm thinking that unless he physically deleted the folder in which he was working, and then got the latest, those commits he claimed to have done would have been recorded somewhere? What are common errors people do when pulling the remote repo? Are there any log files or history i can check to see if i can salvage or at least tell where he was working on this stuff?

any hints to troubleshoot this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Mercurial NEVER loses comitted changes. However, this is probably a case that your user needs some training. Here are points where people get lost:  They pull, and need to merge and haven't merged. They pull, don't need to merge, but need to update.  They didn't commit, they revert changes and pull, losing work, and realize after they lost their data. Etc etc.

Comment: I always only do hg pull --rebase and just lost a commit completely. Whole existance of it disappeared. I know how to use hg and have written hg integrations. I have only one head.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all **backup the tree somewhere** including .hg and everything under it. Then...

```
hg heads
```

...to see if he's just lost track of his commits. If it's there, it's just a case of updating back to it and doing a proper merge.

```
hg log -u 'His Username'
```

...to see if the commits are anywhere in the repo. If they're are there you can then work forward from them.

```
hg shelve --list
```

...to see if he's managed to shelve things somewhere

Take a look in `.hg/strip-backups`, to see if he's managed to strip his changes somehow. Anything else destructive should have left backups in `.hg` too.

That should be a good start. If none of those give any clues then others may be able to suggest some things.

Comment: a user who gets lost like this is probably lost at the command line too. Perhaps such a user might be able to navigate the versions tree in tortoisehg, a little better than from the command line.  I wondered to myself if the user reverted their working copy changes, in order to pull, and realized later that they have lost work. (Would a beginner even known how to shelve things? Doubt it.)

Comment: @WarrenP Yes, they probably would, but I wrote this for the guy who's troubleshooting the problem, not the guy who got himself stuck. I'm not overly familiar with TortoiseHG (as I find it to easy to do the wrong thing in a GUI ;-) ), so all I can offer is CLI advice. I believe TortoiseHG ships with shelve enabled, which is why I listed it.

Comment: Yes, and a clueless newb could actually click a single button and shelve his "dirty working copy changes" without knowing what happened, so it's a good hunch.

Answer (score 1):

I don’t know about TortoiseHG, but usually the first thing would be to check `hg out`.